# Thymeleaf: Use a link with 'th:href' in Javascript

Tags: javascript, thymeleaf

I have the following link:

```
<a th:href="@{/linkToPage}">...</a>
```

which works. But now I have a workaround where I have to "create" this link in Javascript:

```
$('#div').html(
    '<a th:href="@{/linkToPage}">...</a>'
);
```

but now the link does not work anymore. Is there a way to get link work and call the corresponding 'get' method in the controller? Thank you very much.

Comment: Thymeleaf templates are usually executed on server-side while, javascript is usually executed on clients browser. So the browser rendering engine does not know th:ref attributes. Using plain javascript, i guess you can only set the link target without th: prefix

Comment: That works! But generally: is it a good idea to do it that way (btw: I am using Spring MVC and calling a get-method in the controller)

Comment: i am not familiar with Spring MVC but using the thymeleaf engine in different context. If it is related with Spring MVC you might want to add a Spring MVC related Tag to notify a different audience of experts here too

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can achieve it using Thymeleaf script inlining. Try to add `th:inline="javascript"` to the `script` tag and initizialize a `link` variable to use it in your script as follows. You can find out more about Thymeleaf script inlining [here](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#script-inlining-javascript-and-dart).

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/

    var link = /*[[@{/linkToPage}]]*/'';

    $('#div').html(
        '<a href="' + link + '">...</a>'
    );

 /*]]>*/
 <script>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much!

Comment: is there a way to concatenate the link like:

`var linkName = 'linkToPage'; 
var link = /*[[{/ + linkName + }[[*/`

Comment: As @andre-albert  said in comments above, Thymeleaf templates are usually executed on server-side, so you can not put javascript variables in Thymeleaf inline scripting. If I unterstood  what you are asking, you can achieve it this way `var baseLink = /*[[@{/}]]*/; var pageName = '/page-name'; var pageLink = baseLink + pageName;`.